# Could someone provide a basic overview of the process of wiring an object to a variable?

Tags: objective-c

I'm sure this is a very beginner question but I can't seem to find a clear answer.

In most Objective-C resources I've encountered, the saying "wire up" something from one thing to another or "make sure the object is wired to a variable" is used.  I cannot seem to find a good description of what this means.  For instance, how do I "wire" my application window to a variable named appWindowTest or how do I "wire" a controller to be a delegate of the file owner, etc.

Comment: What a dumb kind of jargon, "wire up". I strongly recommend reading the official Apple developer reference library instead.

Comment: It is certainly what it looks like; drawing lines from one object to another.

Comment: If this answer helps you figure it out, please click the checkmark by the answer. It's how StackOverflow marks a question as answered.